# Traversing strings for multiple instances of substrings - freepascal or delphi

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Platform : Lazarus 1.1, FreePascal 2.7.1, Win 7 32-bit.

I have a string value as follows:

```
FileName[12345][45678][6789].jpg
```

By default (assume this is default behaviour 0), my program currently pulls out the last set of numbers from the last pair of square brackets to the farthest right of the filename, i.e. 6789. It does so using this code:

```
if chkbxOverrideUniqueID.Checked then
   IDOverrideValue := StrToInt(edtToggleValue.Text);   
// User is happy to find the right most unique ID
if not chkbxOverrideUniqueID.Checked then      
  LastSquareBracket := RPos(']', strFileName);
  PreceedingSquareBracket := RPosEx('[', strFileName, LastSquareBracket) + 1;
  strFileID := AnsiMidStr(strFileName, PreceedingSquareBracket, LastSquareBracket - PreceedingSquareBracket)
else // User doesn't want to find the rightmost ID. 
  // and now I am stuck!
```

However, I have now added an option for the user to specify a non-default behaviour. e.g if they enter '1', that means "look for the first ID in from the farthest right ID". e.g. [45678], because [6789] is default behaviour 0, remember. If they enter 2, I want it to find [12345].

My question : How do I adapt the above code to achieve this, please?

Comment: Do you have to use the square brackets or are you willing to change that part?

Comment: rposex is FPC only btw, though Synapse' synautil also contaisn them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will return just the numeric value between brackets:

```
uses
  StrUtils;

function GetNumber(const Text: string; Index: Integer): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  OpenPos: Integer;
  ClosePos: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  ClosePos := Length(Text) + 1;
  for I := 0 to Index do
  begin
    ClosePos := RPosEx(']', Text, ClosePos - 1);
    if ClosePos = 0 then
      Exit;
  end;
  OpenPos := RPosEx('[', Text, ClosePos - 1);
  if OpenPos <> 0 then
    Result := Copy(Text, OpenPos + 1, ClosePos - OpenPos - 1);
end;
```

If you'd like that value including those brackets, replace the last line with this:

```
Result := Copy(Text, OpenPos, ClosePos - OpenPos + 1);
```

Comment: You're welcome! Forgot to notice, this code will work properly only with an input string, where each opening bracket has its closing pair.